# JavaScript code only works on IE

Tags: javascript, asp.net, datagrid

on my page i have some JS code. It works on only IE. Doesn't work on Firefox and Google Chrome.

the JS function fires when Datagrid's checkox onclick function..

```
<asp:TemplateColumn Visible="true">
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" Runat="server" onclick="kontrol(this);"></asp:CheckBox>
                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                    </asp:TemplateColumn>
```

here is the JS code..

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">
    var secilenler = "";
    var birim = "";
    function kontrol(obj) {
        var sira = parseInt(obj.id.substring(obj.id.length - 1, obj.id.length)) + 1;
        var grid = document.getElementById("<%= grdIslemler.ClientID %>");
        if (secilenler == "") {
            secilenler += obj.id + "|";
            birim = grid.rows(sira).cells(1).innerHTML;
        }
        else {
            if (birim == grid.rows(sira).cells(1).innerHTML) {
                secilenler += obj.id + "|";
            }
            else {
                secilenler = secilenler.substring(0, secilenler.length - 1);
                var arr = new Array();
                arr = secilenler.split("|");
                for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                    var chk = document.getElementById(arr[i]);
                    chk.checked = false;
                    secilenler = obj.id + "|";
                    birim = grid.rows(sira).cells(1).innerHTML;
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: can you make jsfiddle for this code?

Comment: Can you give us a clue what "doesn't work" means? An error message, the line of code, the symptoms of the failure, what should happen? I can recommend [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) for Firefox for this sort of thing.

Comment: how? i use the js code on datagrid. how can i use datagrid on jsfiddle?

Comment: @freefaller no error message. when i click on the checkbox, js function doesn't fire.